# Should the use of C++ tag to get extra attention for C questions be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, tags

I sometimes see questions where the author is clearly only working in C, yet the C++ tag is included anyways. I then see people offering C++-style solutions to the problem, only to have them ignored or rejected. In such cases, is it correct to remove the C++ tag from the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a lot of people using C are genuinely confused about the differences between the languages. And most C questions are in fact C++ questions too in that almost all C89 features are subsumed in C++. The only real issue occurs when you suggest using  a"real" C++ feature like std::string rather than an array of char, but this doesn't seem to be much of a problem. So I would leave the tags alone, unless it is very, very obvious the question is solely about C.

Answer (score 3):

If an answer using C++-specific features would not be suitable or appropriate, then yes. However, most C programmers these days use a C++ compiler, as there are performance and efficiency improvements to be found there, so it does get to be a bit of a grey area.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that most people, after getting all "Use `boost::Foo`" answers the first time they do that will learn better. Or at least, that is why *I* wouldn't stick a [c++] tag on my c question.

Comment: Hehe, I'm one of those Boost cheerleaders.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if the problem can occur in C++ too (and being a superset and all, it can) you shouldn't remove it. Maybe someone else with the same problem coming to the question with google is using C++, and can therefore use the C++ solutions that have been rejected by the OP.